# Setting up a terminal in VS code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to to open the terminal in VS code the following message pops up. I am a newbie and I am not able to understand all of this

I was trying to configure the auto reload upon saving via node.js and my course showed that I might be able to do this via VS code terminal

The error message when trying to open the VS code terminal

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can first re-install your VS code to remove this error and then go to terminal integration settings and select node.js there.